# Glossaries package: Remove separator between numberlist and seelist

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package using `makeidx` (referred to as Option 2 in the manual). My glossary contains several items which have cross-references to other terms, an example of how one of these is defined is:

```
\newglossaryentry{gls:crossCorrelation}{name={cross-correlation},
description={A mathematical process which is used to determine the similarity of two signals},
see={gls:convolution}
}
```

I want the cross reference to appear on a separate line to the description and page list (the `numberlist` sometimes called the `locationlist` in the manual). To this end I have redefined the `seeformat` command to be:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{
\newline \emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}}
```

The problem I have is that the `seelist` is actually part of the number list (as explained on page 111 of the `glossaries` manual) and thus shares it separator punctuation. As a result the glossary entry for the above example appears as:

> Cross-correlation A mathematical process which is used to determine the similarity
>   of two signals. 26, 49, 
>   See also: convolution

As can be seen above there is an undesirable comma following the `numberlist`.

I have had a good look through the manual and documented code but cannot figure out a way of removing this comma. I had hoped to find the command to build the `numberlist` and assumed there would be a if statement relating to the cross reference list.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

%Setup see formatting of gloaary entries
\renewcommand*{\seename}{See also:}
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{
\newline \emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}}

%Enable glossaries
\makeglossaries

%Gloassry entries
\newglossaryentry{gls:world}{name={World},
    description={A planet capable of supporting life. It is not unheard of for bowls of petunias or indeed whales to fall towards them},
    see={gls:planet,gls:life}
}
\newglossaryentry{gls:planet}{name={planet},
    description={A large object with a radius typically greater than $2000~\mathrm{km}$ which meets the following criteria: is in orbit around the Sun, has sufficient mass for its self-gravity to overcome rigid body forces so that it assumes a hydrostatic equilibrium (nearly round) shape, and (c) has cleared the neighbourhood around its orbit}
}
\newglossaryentry{gls:life}{name={life},
    description={The condition that distinguishes animals and plants from inorganic matter, including the capacity for growth, reproduction, functional activity, and continual change preceding death}
}

\begin{document}
Hello \gls{gls:world}! How is \gls{gls:life} on your \gls{gls:planet}?
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

This is compiled with:

```
pdflatex.exe example.tex
makeindex -s example.ist -t example.glg -o example.gls example.glo
makeindex -s example.ist -t example.alg -o example.acr example.acn
pdflatex.exe example.tex
```

The result of these can be seen below (with the undesirable comma highlighted).

[image: MWE Output]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: MWE has now been added as have compilation instructions

Comment: The comma is printed by `\delimN` which is also between individual numbers in that list.   I am not sure how to change that in a useful way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`makeindex` treats cross-references as a location with a particular format where, typically, the formatting command (`\glsseeformat` in this case) disregards the location. If this doesn't suit your requirements, you can store your cross-references in one of the user keys instead of using the `see` key. You then need to write a glossary style that uses this information. Adapting your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

%Enable glossaries
\makeglossaries

%Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{gls:world}{name={World},
    description={A planet capable of supporting life. It is not unheard of for bowls of petunias or indeed whales to fall towards them},
    user1={gls:planet,gls:life}
}
\newglossaryentry{gls:planet}{name={planet},
    description={A large object with a radius typically greater than $2000~\mathrm{km}$ which meets the following criteria: is in orbit around the Sun, has sufficient mass for its self-gravity to overcome rigid body forces so that it assumes a hydrostatic equilibrium (nearly round) shape, and (c) has cleared the neighbourhood around its orbit}
}
\newglossaryentry{gls:life}{name={life},
    description={The condition that distinguishes animals and plants from inorganic matter, including the capacity for growth, reproduction, functional activity, and continual change preceding death}
}

\newglossarystyle{crossreflist}%
{% base it on list (adapt as required)
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
  \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
     \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2%
% check if the user1 key has been supplied:
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}%
    {% do cross-reference
      \newline
      \glsletentryfield{\crossrefs}{##1}{useri}%
      \glsseeformat[See also:]{\crossrefs}{}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
}
\setglossarystyle{crossreflist}

\begin{document}
Hello \gls{gls:world}! How is \gls{gls:life} on your \gls{gls:planet}?

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting glossary]

Comment: Cheers. Not 100 % there but works nicely for now.